# Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081 (How to fix?)

Tags: react-native

**Show this error whenever I run react-native run-android**

react-native run-android

info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 1598 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 8 workers...
info JS server already running.
info Installing the app...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 808ms

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

**How to fix this?**

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to navigate in the android directory and run this command
`chmod 755 android/gradlew`
and then try to run the npm run-android command.